# How to plot a custom colorbar from list in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-analysis, colorbar

I want to make a custom colorbar in matplotlib. This issue is that when I give it a list of colors it shows discrete colors and I want the colorbar to be continuous.

This is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as image
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = ListedColormap(['white', 'orange'], N=4) #colorMap
map_int = ax3.imshow(integrated, extent=(60, 70, 23.5, 25.0), cmap = cmap, zorder=-1, aspect="auto")
cbar_int = fig1.colorbar(map_int, ax=ax3, fraction=0.046, pad=0.04 )
cbar_int.set_label('Ramp', size=15, rotation=90)
cbar_int.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15) 
map_int.set_clim(1, 20) #colorbar_limit
plt.show()
```

[image]

It shows this type of discrete chart and I want it to be a continuous ramp between white and orange.

Comment: You can use `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('name', ['white','orange'] )` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list)

Comment: @JohanC I survived back surgery, and that [continuous colormap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko7gc.png) reminds me of [orange cicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B36o9.png)

Comment: I hope you are doing well. It sounds quite heavy